# Communication between two signalr clients on the same computer

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I have an asp.net mvc5 site on a remote server and a c# desktop app on the client pc. I want the client browser (with the asp.net web opened inside) to be able to send messages to the c# desktop app (for example info about the currently logged in user on the site) and vice versa. I decided to give SignalR a try, but the problem is that I cannot identify the other client I want to send the message to.

Not as if I couldn't create an identificator for the c# client, the problem rather lies in the browser client. Even if I identify the app's device, I cannot check if the browser is running on the same computer, because javascript nor anything else doesn't provide any way to verify it- at least not one I know about.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem in the past? Is there any way to fix this signalr approach or do I need to look at completely different solutions? I've read that WCF might be a good option in similar situations, but I'm completely unfamiliar with it and thus I don't know if it would work in this specific case.